# Automatic brightness adjustment in windows 8.1

Tags: laptop, drivers, display, windows-8.1, nvidia-quadro

I'm having some issues turning off the automatic dim settings in windows 8.1.
Whenever I switch to my desktop the screen darkens, if I drag a window into view it brightens again.

I've tried setting every possible power settings option to full brightness - all the time, I've adjusted the advanced power settings so that "Enable adaptive brightness" is off in every plan, I've updated my graphics driver to the latest version (Nvidia Quadro K3000M - driver version 340.84) and still I cannot get it to remain at the same level of brightness.

I do not know what else to try and this is driving me insane.
Can anyone offer some guidance as to what option I'm suppose to turn off?

I have a (corporate) HP EliteBook 8770w with a fresh windows 8.1 install.

Comment: Be sure to check if there is any other power controlling software. I know several of my Lenovo machines come with a stock "Lenovo Power Manager" that took precedence over native power controls.

Comment: As far as I know there is HP power management software running. NVidia has its own display software but it is not being used.

Comment: If there is HP power management software running as you mention, I'd first disable it entirely to see if the problem persists

Comment: I made a little typo there. I actually meant to say *no* HP software is running. But just in case I double checked and there shouldn't be anything interfering.